# While playing Squad Deathmatch, some players are blue

Tags: battlefield-4

In Squad Deatchmatch, all players are in one of four squads, so all friendly players should have a green icon (signifying that they are in the same squad as oneself), however I was playing a Squad Deathmatch with 48 players and noticed that some of the friendly players had a blue icon instead, as if they were in another squad but on the same team. Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug. You're right that all icons should be green / squad's color.

Comment: Do you have a source for it being a bug?

Comment: The gametype description is pretty straightforward: One squad (yours) vs other squads. There's no possible teammates out of your squad.

Answer (score 0):

Green = Squad

Blue = Team

Red = Other team

You'd have to be in the squad with them.  Not just on their team that is confusingly labeled Squad Alpha, A, or w/e.

Comment: Aren't all other squads enemies? So there should be no team with blue members. Or did I not understand what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

The squad leader has the privilege to kick any player from their squad if wanted. They can not fully kick the player from the squad so instead the player receives the blue icon and they can not spawn on anyone from the squad. This is to make the person want to manually switch squads in order to regain spawn points.This person can still rejoin the squad whenever though, but the squad leader can still "blueberry" them from the squad once they've rejoined.